# Array Multipart[] file upload using Feign client

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I am trying to upload Array of Multipart file object using feign client.
This is the service am trying to call using Feign client.

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> manageFileUpload(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files)
```

I tried using,Feign client Annotation,

```
@FeignClient(value = "UPLOADUTILITIES", configuration = Upload.MultipartSupportConfig.class, fallback = UploadFallback.class)
```

My Method,

```
@RequestMapping(name = "upload", value = "/object", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Headers("Content-Type: multipart/form-data")
ResponseEntity<Object> manageFileUpload(@Param("files") MultipartFile[] files);
```

I was rewarded by the error,

```
"message": "Type definition error: [simple type, class java.io.FileDescriptor]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile[0]->org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile[\"inputStream\"]->java.io.FileInputStream[\"fd\"])",
```

Then by referring this [link](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign-form#spring-multipartfile-and-spring-cloud-netflix-feignclient-support).I tried in my client side, the blow code.

```
public class MultipartSupportConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> messageConverters;

    @Bean
    public Encoder feignFormEncoder() {
        return new SpringFormEncoder(new SpringEncoder(messageConverters));
    }
}
```

Then by the code example, i changed my MultiPart File object into File Object.Now my request got fired, but i got `Not a multipart request`.

I tried this https://github.com/pcan/feign-client-test#feign-client-test,

I created a class and used the encoder class, and changed my encoder as FeignSpringFormEncoder,

Still I am getting No serializer found error.

Could anyone share a simple client, server example with Array of Multipart file request, using feign cleint. Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: No, am yet to solve DarkFeud