# How to upload multiple Multipart files using feign client in Microservice architecture

Tags: java, microservices, multipart, spring-cloud-feign

I'm trying to upload multiple multipart file using feign client, but I am not being able to do so.

After few research, 
[File Upload Using Feign - multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752779/file-upload-using-feign-multipart-form-data)

[File upload spring cloud feign client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46522304/file-upload-spring-cloud-feign-client)

[Array Multipart[] file upload using Feign client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580267/array-multipart-file-upload-using-feign-client)

Client side:

```
@FeignClient(name = "file-server", configuration = {FileUploadService.MultipartSupportConfig.class})
@RequestMapping
public interface FileUploadService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<FileUploadResponseDTO> handleFileUpload(@RequestPart(name = "file") MultipartFile[] file);
    @Configuration
    public class MultipartSupportConfig {

        @Autowired
        private ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> messageConverters;

        @Bean
        @Primary
        @Scope("prototype")
        public Encoder feignEncoder() {
            return new SpringFormEncoder(new SpringEncoder(messageConverters));
        }
    }
```

Module I'm trying to access:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
@ApiOperation(UPLOAD_FILE)
public List<FileUploadResponseDTO> uploadFiles(@RequestPart(name = "file") MultipartFile[] file){
    System.out.println("****hello ****");

    return fileUploadService.uploadFiles(file);
}
```

The above works fine for a single Multipart file but it shows following error for multiple files:

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is feign.codec.EncodeException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [[Lorg.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;] and content type [multipart/form-data]] with root cause
feign.codec.EncodeException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [[Lorg.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;] and content type [multipart/form-data]

Answer (score 0):

you should set the encoder during feign configuration:

```
public class FeignSimpleEncoderConfig {
    @Bean
    public Encoder encoder() {
        return new FormEncoder();
    }
}
```

Comment: Still the same issue : Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [[Lorg.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;] and content type [multipart/form-data]",

Comment: I thinks you miss some point!
Let's verify as below :

```@Configuration
public class FeignSimpleEncoderConfig {
    @Bean
    public Encoder encoder() {
        return new FormEncoder();
    }
}```

And then use it in feign interface : 

```@FeignClient(name = "file-server", configuration =FeignSimpleEncoderConfig.class)
@RequestMapping
public interface FileUploadService { ... }
```

Comment: Got NullPointerException. Are you sure the above code works? Do we need any dependencies?

Comment: I used only this :        
`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
         </dependency>`

Comment: This is [sample project](https://github.com/sovannarithcheav/spring-cloud-feign-example.git)

Comment: Seems like there is already a project in your m2 of io.github.openfeign.form. Also, when I try to fetch multipart file in user-service, zero files are retrieved.